# Asymmetric links in mininet

Tags: mininet

I want to use mininet to test a small network with some asymmetric links, but I have not found any information about it. Could someone have an idea to simulate these kind of links.

Comment: What do you mean by asymmetric links?

Comment: I mean an ADSL connection between a host and a switch. I can set TClink with a bw specific but this would work both ways ( upload and download). I would like to have a bw for upload  and a different one for download.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set different limitations to the different interfaces of the same link. As [this link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/pull/650/files) suggests, assuming that in your topology you have created a host connected to a switch, like this :

```
switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
host1 = self.addHost('h1')
self.addLink(host1, switch1, bw = 1000)
```

you can set different bandwidth to one of the host's interfaces like this :

```
intf = h1.intf()
info( "Setting BW Limit for Interface " + str(intf) + " to " + str(TARGET_BW) + "\n" )
intf.config(bw = TARGET_BW, smooth_change = True)   //smooth_change=True or False
```

assuming that you have defined something like :

```
TARGET_BW = 500
```

after your imports.